# Custom itemization with more nesting depth and varying labels

Tags: enumitem, layout

I would like to use `enumitem` to define an `itemize` environment which goes beyond a depth of 4. I was able to come up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myItemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[myItemize]{label=\textbullet}
\setlistdepth{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item 1st level
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 2nd level
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 3rd level
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 4th level
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{myItemize}
\item 1st level
    \begin{myItemize}
    \item 2nd level
        \begin{myItemize}
        \item 3rd level
            \begin{myItemize}
            \item 4th level
                \begin{myItemize}
                \item 5th level
                    \begin{myItemize}
                    \item 6th level
                        \begin{myItemize}
                        \item 7th level
                            \begin{myItemize}
                            \item 8th level
                                \begin{myItemize}
                                \item 9th level
                                \end{myItemize}
                            \end{myItemize}
                        \end{myItemize}
                    \end{myItemize}
                \end{myItemize}
            \end{myItemize}
        \end{myItemize}
    \end{myItemize}
\end{myItemize}
\end{document}
```

Which renders the following:

[image]

I still have two problems:

1. The custom `myItemize` bullet list does not have consistent spacing. After the 4th level the subsequent bullets are closer together in the horizontal (and vertical?) directions
2. The custom `myItemize` bullet list uses the same label for all depths. I'd like for it to use the same labels as the default `itemize` environment. Beyond the default max depth of 4 I'd simply want it to repeat the cycle of bullet labels. Namely bullet, dash, star, dot, bullet, dash, star, dot, and so on and so forth.

I've skimmed through both enumitem.pdf and layman.pdf, and I'm not quite sure where to start. Would anyone be able to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual solution after playing with the values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlist{myItemize}{itemize}{9}

\setlist[myItemize,1]{label=\labelitemi,itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[myItemize,2]{label=\labelitemii,itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[myItemize,3]{label=\labelitemiii,itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[myItemize,4]{label=\labelitemiv,itemindent=0.25em}
\setlist[myItemize,5]{label=\labelitemi,itemindent=0.75em}
\setlist[myItemize,6]{label=\labelitemii,itemindent=1.25em}
\setlist[myItemize,7]{label=\labelitemiii,itemindent=1.75em}
\setlist[myItemize,8]{label=\labelitemiv,itemindent=2.25em}
\setlist[myItemize,9]{label=\labelitemi,itemindent=3em}

\setlistdepth{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item 1st level
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 2nd level
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 3rd level
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 4th level
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{myItemize}
\item\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\coordinate(A);\end{tikzpicture} 1st level
    \begin{myItemize}
    \item 2nd level
        \begin{myItemize}
        \item 3rd level
            \begin{myItemize}
            \item 4th level
                \begin{myItemize}
                \item 5th level
                    \begin{myItemize}
                    \item 6th level
                        \begin{myItemize}
                        \item 7th level
                            \begin{myItemize}
                            \item 8th level
                                \begin{myItemize}
                                \item\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\coordinate(B);\end{tikzpicture} 9th level
                                \end{myItemize}
                            \end{myItemize}
                        \end{myItemize}
                    \end{myItemize}
                \end{myItemize}
            \end{myItemize}
        \end{myItemize}
    \end{myItemize}
\end{myItemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[opacity=0.5](A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not perfect ... but I am bored to play more... :P.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. A couple of follow up questions: I see you're assigning incrementally increasing values of `itemindent` starting from depth 4. For depths 1, 2 and 3 you are assigning a constant `itemindent=0.25em`. Why is this? Also, you claim this is "not perfect". I personally don't see any way to improve this, could you elaborate on how someone *would* make it "perfect"? In any case thanks for your response.

Comment: @user32882 ... I didn't knew before your answer that even simple itemize has no constant spaces there from depth to depth. So, I can't help... But my way would not be this since there is easier to define a new enumeration environment without these tricks of the `enumitem` ... Please un-accept the answer of mine and wait for other answers too. If I find the time later I will try to add my way of custom enumerate environments

Comment: to be honest this answer works for me. I was just wondering why some aspects of your implementation were the way they were. I don't really see a need to un-accept.

Comment: It was try-fail-adjust ... I realized this way that the fourth item has less indentation that the first three depths... Actually I suppose this is something like using a "gold sequence" of factors that makes better the appearance... like a number 1.6*height of a floor is the total height with the roof etc (just an example of "gold beauty") ... I didn't used really accurate terms here... But hope you got my point